# Defining the order that distinct items are listed in

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, distinct

I am trying to construct a simple site which compares the best time for a race for a number of individuals, however, I am having a lot of difficulty using `distinct` which seems to be causing me a number of unexpected problems...

I have two databases - `Result` and `Athlete` (athlete has many results)

I am attempting to identify the quickest time for each athlete for a specific event and then put them in order. In order to do this, I need to create a list of unique athlete names, BUT they also have to be in the sequence of increasing time (i.e. slower). I am currently using:

```
 <% @filtered_names = Result.where(:event_name => params[:justevent]).joins(:athlete).order('performance_time_hours ASC').order('performance_time_mins ASC').order('performance_time_secs ASC').order('performance_time_msecs ASC').select('distinct athlete_id') %>
```

This appeared to be working, however, I have discovered that if the last entry in the `results` database is the slowest across all athletes, this athlete ends up at the end of my list of names, EVEN IF one of their previous results is the fastest of all times recorded!

Is someone able to tell me whether `distinct` works in some strange way and how I can get around this issue?  If the bottom result is the quickest the script works perfectly as it is...

For the sake of completeness, I need this information in order to run the following code:

```
 <% @filtered_names.each do |filtered_name| %>
 <% @currentathleteperformance = Result.where(:event_name => params[:justevent]).where(:athlete_id => filtered_name.athlete_id).order('performance_time_hours ASC').order('performance_time_mins ASC').order('performance_time_secs ASC').order('performance_time_msecs ASC').first() %>
 <% @currentathlete = Athlete.where(:id => filtered_name.athlete_id).first() %>

    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.performance_time_mins %>:<%= @currentathleteperformance.performance_time_secs %>:<%= @currentathleteperformance.performance_time_msecs %> </td>
    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.wind_speed %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.athlete_name %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathlete.gender %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathlete.sec %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.competition_name %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.round %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.position %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathleteperformance.performance_date %></td>
    <td><%= @currentathlete.coach_name %></td>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can there be multiple performance_times for one athlete per event?

Comment: Yes sorry i didn't make that clear.  If i have one performance for each athlete, the code works correctly.   The problem comes in when there are two or more results for an athlete

Comment: You did not name your database system, yet. My answer should work in pretty much any RDBMS but I tested with PostgreSQL. Link about `time` is for PostgreSQL, too. There is a [`time` type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/time.html) in MySQL and others as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 1 column `performance_time` of [data type `time`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) to replace all of:

```
performance_time_hours
performance_time_mins
performance_time_secs
performance_time_msecs
```

Or `interval` if more than 24 hours for one performance are possible.

I am no good with Ruby syntax, but the query to get what you want could look like this - assuming that athletes can perform multiple times per event and `event_name` is unique:

```
SELECT athlete_id, min(performance_time) AS min_performance_time
FROM   result
WHERE  event_name = params[:justevent]
GROUP  BY athlete_id
ORDER  BY min(performance_time), athlete_id
```

I order by `athlete_id` in addition, but that's just an arbitrary measure to break ties in a stable manner.

`DISTINCT` just takes the *first* row according to the sort order for every set of duplicates. To achieve the same result with `DISTINCT` you'd need a subselect:

```
SELECT athlete_id, performance_time
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT ON (athlete_id)
           athlete_id, performance_time
    FROM   result
    WHERE  event_name = params[:justevent]
    ORDER  BY athlete_id, performance_time
    ) a
ORDER BY performance_time, athlete_id
```

You have to `ORDER  BY athlete_id` to get distinct athletes and cannot order by minimum `performance_time` first on the same query level. Therefore, you'd have to put the result of the `SELECT DISTINCT` in a subselect and sort by time in additional step.